# Set custom Notification sound from internal storage

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications

I am trying to play notification sound from my internal storage. 
First I downloaded a file when anyone installs an application and then I want to use that notification sound that is downloaded in internal storage. 
Following is the code that I am using but notification is playing system sound instead.

```
 Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(this)
            .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
            .setContentText(text)
            .setContentTitle(waktu)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_logo)
            .setVibrate(new long[]{500, 1000})
            .setSound(Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                                + "/Folder", Name + ".mp3")))
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .build();

    notification.flags |=
            Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT |
                    Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;
    notification.ledOnMS = 300;
    notification.ledOffMS = 3000;

    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    // Send the notification.
    mNotificationManager.notify(0, notification);
```

Comment: you need to place the file in "raw" folder of resources and then use

Comment: You cannot place in raw file, as I am downloading the file